# CSS image corners don't round off consistently. Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, rounded-corners

I'm working on a mobile app.  It's a protected website using jQuery mobile for the presentation framework. The protected content, the list of team members, is delivered via Ajax after authentication and identity verification. Here's a screen shot from my phone. The site is responsive, and can be used by desktop, tablet or mobile.  Obviously it's optimized for mobile with `tel:`, `sms:` and `mailto:` links

[image: Odd CSS Troubles with Rounded Corners on image display]

I don't understand the odd corners on the images. This is erratic, and happens 75% of the time.  This only happens to the upper left hand corner of the top image in the list, and the bottom left hand corner of the bottom entry in the list, no matter how long the list is.  Generally, the corner displays round if you refresh the screen. I'm sure its some sort of timing issue, but I've not seen it before. I'm using iphone 6 with Safari browser for that screen shot.  I see the exact same thing in Chrome on my laptop in desktop mode.  I don't think this is a device or browser dependent issue.

HTML:

```
<div id="page6_team_phones">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
        <h2>Phone Contact List</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" id="phonelist" class="ui-listview">
            <li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
                <div class="img_container"><img class="img-photo" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-15..."></div>
                <div class="userName">Andrea Apple</div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <div class="phoneNumber"><a href="tel:+11234567891">1234567891</a></div>
                <div class="sms"><a href="sms:+11234567891"><img src="../images/crosstxt-icon.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="email"><a href="mailto:123@email.com"><img src="../images/email-icon.png"></a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
                <div class="img_container"><img class="img-photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/KOXOBiN.gif"></div>
                <div class="userName">Bill Banana</div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <div class="phoneNumber"><a href="tel:+19876543211">9876543211</a></div>
                <div class="sms"><a href="sms:+19876543211"><img src="../images/crosstxt-icon.jpg"></a></div>
                <div class="email"><a href="mailto:456@fake.com"><img src="../images/email-icon.png"></a></div>
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
.img_container {
    float: left;
}
.img-photo {
    height: 24vw;     /*  photo = square aspect ratio  */
    width: 24vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20%;
}
```

Anybody understand exactly what is causing this issue? Why only top left and bottom left?  Best way to improve the display?

Comment: Can you replicate this on JSFiddle?

Comment: Here is a quick jsfiddle.  Heck, the issue is evident in a static display, without the whole $.ajax round trip...    https://jsfiddle.net/aumztghn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspection, I've found that jQuery mobile has some CSS that affects the first and last elements in your list. You could modify the styles directly, but it's probably much better to override the jQuery mobile CSS by adding `!important` to the property (`border-radius: 20% !important;`). Doing that in your JSFiddle fixed it for me.

Here's a [fixed example](https://jsfiddle.net/mb84Lvpc/).

Comment: `!important` Now you are talking religion, sigh...  I see that now `at.ui-listview>li.ui-first-child img:first-child:not(.ui-li-icon) {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    border-top-left-radius: inherit;
}` . I still don't understand why sometimes its there and other times not..  Clearly the jsfiddle is 100%.  thx for your response

Comment: Yeah, I get `!important` is a bit of a touchy subject, but in this circumstance you'd either have to modify jQuery mobile's css file (which has its own slew of problems), change your approach, or add `!important` to override its styles for this one particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already an accepted answer but it feels more like a patch than a full understanding.

That rule only triggers for any element that is NOT of a class `.ui-li-icon` as you can see below:

`.ui-listview>li.ui-first-child img:first-child:not(.ui-li-icon)`

So simply add that class to your image like so:

`<img class="img-photo ui-li-icon" src="https://images.unsplash.com/..." onclick="openImgModal(this.src)">`

This will tell CSS to NOT apply those rules.

Comment: Good catch, You are right, moreover there isn't any nesting inside the `li`. It seems to me it's neither a list but instead a series of cards, so IMHO using a JQM `listview` widget isn't necessary anymore.